# Can I use my Flower Tabs/Jars from the field?

Tags: super-mario-rpg-2023

In the original game, flower tabs and jars were used to increase your flower points permanently. You'd typically use it from the field out of battle by going to your items in the pause menu and choosing it.

However in the new game, when I tried to use it, a window pops up telling me:

> You can use recovery items in the field with <kbd>X</kbd>.

[image: message]
*and it's not even used...*

I'm confused, can I not use it? Did they change how this works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a little different in this game. You aren't meant to use it from the pause menu, there are separate menus that you would open by pressing the appropriate buttons while in the field (not the pause menu). I thought the message was indicating I have to use it in battle for some reason.

- <kbd>Y</kbd> - Opens the `Special Moves` menu to use a special move.
- <kbd>X</kbd> - Opens the `Items` menu to use an item.

I have to use it from the new `Items` menu in the field.

[image: new items menu]
*so this is where I need to go.*